# Git diff: show only removed (not moved) lines

Tags: git, grep, diff

Git `diff` has the terrific `--color-moved` option. So I see that Git can detect when lines are moved, but not actually removed.

I need to detect lines removed but not removed. Simply grepping the output of `git diff` for lines that start with `-` will not help because that will capture moved lines as well. Can we either:

1. Configure `git diff` to show only the removed lines, but not the moved lines?
2. Configure `git diff --color-moved` to use a different leading character for moved lines, so that we could grep for a leading `-` on the output to find the removed lines?
3. Grep the output of `git diff --color-moved` for the (default) red lines, as those are the removed lines?

Comment: What is the point? `--color-moved` only detects moved lines of a certain minimal length and character composition. What is it when you have an added line with `}` in one position and a removed `}` in a different position? Is it a moved line even though `--color-moved` does not mark it as moved?

Comment: @j6t The point is to find lines that have been deleted. My current use case is for a notes file, not code.

Answer (score 1):

A bit fragile but:

```bash
git diff --color-moved=plain --color=always |
perl -pe 's/^\e\[31m-/!/; s/\e\[[0-9;]*m//g'
```

- set moved lines to a different colour
- force colour even in pipes
- use Perl to:

  - replace the prefix character on deleted lines
  - remove the ANSI escape sequences

Comment: Thank you. Though the line that you suggest did not work (On my system it did not remove any lines), the hint to grep for `31m` did help. The final line is: ```git diff --color-moved=plain --color=always personal/arab-israeli-conflict.org | grep "\[31m-"```.

Comment: my code was just supposed to flag the deleted lines (by changing `-` to `!`). glad you got something that works for you